# How to stylized back-to-back or consecutive western-style quote marks?

Tags: writing

It seems most punctuation marks in Chinese are automatically stylized with spaces. Periods (。), commas (，), question marks (？), exclamation marks (！) and even book title marks (《》), as oxford likes to call them, all have spaces either in front or behind them.

Western-style quote marks (“”) on the other hand do not.

How should they be stylized?

Back-to-back quotes look even worse. I'm working on the following sentence:

> 《明珠缘》第三十七回：“体乾醉了，应星却未吃酒，兼之少年精壮，隔席把张体乾轻轻一把提过来，丢翻在地，拳打脚踢。”“丢翻”意为打翻或摔倒在地等，可能源于武林。

Where we have this ugly looking

> ”“

in the middle. An end quote mark followed by an opening quote mark with no spaces in between.

Is this correct? (It doesn't look so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Chinese quotation mark is called [引号](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E5%BC%95%E5%8F%B7) 「」 『』
>
> “.......” =「......。」

~

> 單引号 (single quotation mark) 「」
>
> Use 單引号 for quote「........。」

~

> 雙引号 (double quotation mark) 『』
>
> Use 雙引号 for quote within quote...『....「...」....。』

~

> *An end quote mark followed by an opening quote mark with no spaces in between.*
>
> Is this correct?

There have to be space between back to back quote, Chinese quotation mark is automatically stylized with spaces.

《明珠缘》第三十七回：『体乾醉了，应星却未吃酒，兼之少年精壮，隔席把张体乾轻轻一把提过来，丢翻在地，拳打脚踢。「丢翻」意为打翻或摔倒在地等，可能源于武林。』

If you use English quotation mark for quotes, you have to put space between back to back quotes as if it was Chinese quotation mark .

《明珠缘》第三十七回："体乾醉了，应星却未吃酒，兼之少年精壮，隔席把张体乾轻轻一把提过来，丢翻在地，拳打脚‌​踢。" " '丢翻' 意为打翻或摔倒在地等，可能源于武林。"

Comment: But my material specifically requests western-style quotations

Comment: You need space between back to back quotes.《明珠缘》第三十七回："体乾醉了，应星却未吃酒，兼之少年精壮，隔席把张体乾轻轻一把提过来，丢翻在地，拳打脚踢"。" '丢翻' 意为打翻或摔倒在地等，可能源于武林"。

Comment: I believe the period should go in the quotes

Comment: Yes, according to the rule, I should  put punctuation marks inside the quotation mark, but for some reason, it look better outside.... when Chinese text is written in English typing format.

Comment: I've only ever seen the opposite

Answer (score -1):

Just use any chinese Pinyin input program like [搜狗拼音输入法](http://pinyin.sogou.com/index.php) to input chinese quotation, the quotation is different betweeen tradtional Chinese and simplified chinese.
《明珠缘》第三十七回：“体乾醉了，应星却未吃酒，兼之少年精壮，隔席把张体乾轻轻一把提过来，丢翻在地，拳打脚踢。”“丢翻”意为打翻或摔倒在地等，可能源于武林”。

Comment: didn't address my `”“` question at all